# Evaluate $\space\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{n}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos t}{\left(1+t^2\right)^n}dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

Find the limit $$ \large
\space\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{n}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos t}{\left(1+t^2\right)^n}dt
$$

Comment: Why is the limit clear? @AntonioVargas What is this called?

Comment: Now I remember.

Comment: Rewrite as $$2 \sqrt{n} \int_0^{\infty} dt \, \cos{t} \, e^{-n \log{(1+t^2)}}$$ and use Laplace's method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For big $n$ the integrand is cleary dominated from the region around $t=0$. we therefore might write ($\epsilon\ll 1$ )
$$
I(n)\approx \int_{-\epsilon}^{\epsilon}\cos(t)\frac{1}{(1+t^2)^n}=\int_{-\epsilon}^{\epsilon}\cos(t)e^{-n\log(1+t^2)}\approx\int_{-\epsilon}^{\epsilon}\cos(t)e^{-nt^2}\approx\int_{-\epsilon}^{\epsilon}e^{-nt^2}
$$

where we have used $\log(1+x)\approx x$ and $\cos(x)\approx 1$ for $x\ll1$.
The usual trick is now that we can extend the limits of integration back to $\pm \infty$ inducing only an exponentially small error (all steps can be made rigourous by the method of steepest descent). We are therefore left with a standard Gaussian integral

$$
I(n)\approx\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-nt^2}=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{n}}
$$

and we can conclude that

$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sqrt{n}I(n)= \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sqrt{n}\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{n}}=\sqrt{\pi}
$$

Comment: "All steps can be made rigourous by the method of steepest descent"
What does this mean? Can you provide me to a relevant link that explains this? THANKYOU

Comment: @GohP.iHan my approach is pretty heuristic. For example the statement that one can reexpand the intervall of integration. This can be made rigorous by using Steepest Descent method for example

Comment: Oh just [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_steepest_descent)? Got it, let me learn something new!! TQ

Answer (score 1):

Or you could just use $x=t\sqrt{n}$ followed by the dominated convergence theorem to get$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{\Bbb R}(1+\tfrac{x^{2}}{n})^{-n}\cos\tfrac{x}{\sqrt{n}}dx=\int_{\Bbb R}e^{-x^2}dx=\sqrt{\pi}.$$